# Calculate limit (squeeze theorem?)

Tags: real-analysis

I have to calculate this limit:

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\bigg(\frac{A^n}{n}+\frac{B^n}{n^2}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
Where $A,B >0$. I thought about assuming that $A\geq B$ and then use squeeze theorem, but I don't know if I can do it.

Comment: together and then take out larger one of  A,B

Answer (score 0):

For $A\ge B$, the expression becomes $A(\frac{1}{n}+(\frac{B}{A})^n/n^2)^\frac{1}{n}$.  which $\to A$ as $n\to \infty$.  The expression in parenthesis $\approx e^{-\frac{ln(n)}{n}}\to 1$.

Comment: If $B>A$ Then take out $B$ as the common factor and do similar things

Comment: @Gareth Ma Using your comment, the general solution for the limit = max(A,B).